# Sorting an array together with other array in jq

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, jq

I have two arrays in a structure but between elements of arrays has logical connections. (Eg. `comments[1]` belongs to `records[1]`, `comments[2]` belongs to `records[2]`)

These arrays are sorted by alpabetical order of records array.
When I want to add a new element for both array then I have sort both arrays. For records array it is easy, but the elements of comments array have to move same way as each element of record.

Input:

```json
{
  "records":
    [
     {"content":"a"},
     {"content":"z"}
    ], 
     "comments":[
         {"content":"something"},
         {"content":"anything"}
     ]
}
```

New elements are added to the end of arrays:

````json
{ 
  "records":[
      {"content":"a"},
      {"content":"z"},
      {"content":"b"}
  ],
  "comments":[
      {"content":"something"},
      {"content":"anything"},
      {"content":"new element"}
  ]
}

Expected sorted output:

```json
{
  "records":[
     {"content":"a"},
     {"content":"b"},
     {"content":"z"}
  ],
  "comments":[
     {"content":"something"},
     {"content":"new element"},
     {"content":"anything"}
  ]
}
````

I tried `"to_elements`, `map`, `transpose` and `add`functions without any (partial) result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than appending the new elements to the arrays, you could use `bsearch` to find the insertion point, and then use that to perform the two insertions. Specifically, if $x is not in a sorted array, then the insertion point of $x in the array is `-1 - bsearch($x)`.

You might find this helper function useful:

```
def insert($x;$i): .[:$i]+[$x]+.[$i:];
```

### Solution

Here then is a solution for the problem at hand:

```
# It is assumed that (.|f) is a sorted array
def insert_into_sorted($x; f; $y; g):
  def insert($x;$i): .[:$i]+[$x]+.[$i:];
  (f|bsearch($x)) as $ix
  | (if $ix > -1 then $ix else -1 - $ix end) as $i
  | f|=insert($x; $i)
  | g|=insert($y; $i) ;

insert_into_sorted( {"content": "b"}; .records; 
                    {"content": "new element"}; .comments)
```